# Searching for Terms and Printing lines in a Text File

Tags: scala, text-files

The file name is searcher.scala and I want to be able to type:

```
scala searcher.scala "term I want to find" "file I want to search through" "new file with new lines"
```

I tried this code but keeps saying I have an empty iterator

```
import java.io.PrintWriter

val searchTerm = args(0)
val input = args(1) 
val output = args(2)

val out = new PrintWriter(output);

val listLines = scala.io.Source.fromFile(input).getLines

for (line <- listLines) 
{ 
    { out.println("Line: " + line) }

    def term (x: String): Boolean = {x == searchTerm} 
    val newList = listLines.filter(term)
    println(listLines.filter(term))
}
out.close;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have iterator `listLines` and you read it few times but iterator is one-time object:

- `for (line <- listLines)`
- `val newList = listLines.filter(term)`
- `println(listLines.filter(term))`

You need revise your code to avoid repeat using of iterator.